# What's the connection between P/E ratio and growth?

Tags: investing, price-earnings-ratio

Is there an exact formula for that if we can predict the growth accurately?

For example:

> Using discounted cash flow analysis, the impact of earnings growth and
>   inflation can be evaluated. Using constant historical earnings growth
>   rate of 3.8 and post-war S&P 500 returns of 11% (including 4%
>   inflation) as the discount rate, the fair P/E is obtained as 14.42. A
>   stock growing at 10% for next five years would have a fair P/E of
>   18.65.

How come a 11% returns correspond to 14.42 P/E ratio? 100%/14.42 is not 11%

Comment: Where did that quote come from?

Comment: Wikipedia is the source of the quote. it was the first hit on goggle for the phrase: fair p/e  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Price%E2%80%93earnings_ratio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, the price-earnings ratio is price over earnings, easy enough. But obviously earnings are not static. In the case of a growing company, the earnings will be higher in the future. There will be *extra* earnings, above and beyond what the stock has right now. You should consider the future earnings in your estimate of what the company is worth now.

One snag: Those extra earnings are future money. Future-money is an interesting thing, it's actually worth less than present-money- because of things like inflation, but also opportunity cost.  So if you bought $100 in money that you'll have 20 years from now, you'd expect to pay less than $100. (The US government can sell you that money. It's called a Series EE Savings Bond and it would cost you $50. I think. Don't quote me on that, though, [ask the Treasury](http://www.treasurydirect.gov/indiv/research/indepth/ebonds/res_e_bonds_eeratesandterms.htm).)

So you can't compare future money with present-money directly, and you can't just add those dollars to the earnings . You need to compute a **discount**. That's what discounted cash-flow analysis is about: figuring out the future cash flow, and then discounting the future figuring out what it's worth now.

The actual way you use the discount rate in your formula is a little scarier than simple division, though, because it involves discounting each year's earnings (in this case, someone has asserted a discount of 11% a year, and five years of earnings growth of 10%). [Wikipedia gives us the formula for the value of the future cash flow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discounted_cash_flow#Discounted_cash_flows):

> [image: discounting formula here]

essentially adding all the future cash flows together, and then discounting them by a (compounded) rate. Please forgive me for not filling this formula out; I'm here for theory, not math. :)

Comment: The problem is if the company grows by 11% and pay no dividen, couldn't that complicated formula be simplified?

Comment: Paying a dividend is irrelevant to the P/E ratio: the company has the cash, you can ignore whether they distribute it immediately. Can you simplify the formula? Depends! Do you know enough calculus to think `Σ(CF[n]/((1+r)^n))` is simpler? How about if we replace `CF[n]` with `CF[0] * (1+g)^(n)` (where `g` is the earnings growth rate)? Maybe the substituted version could be shuffled... but it obscures the fact that a company's profits aren't symbols and formulas! It's a series of real-world transactions. (Besides, I'm rusty on my calculus.)